# Why is JavaFx datepicker1.setOnAction event firing whenever datepicker1.setValue( ) is complied?

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, setvalue, javafx-datepicker

Suppose I have two datepickers -> `date1` and `date2`. Whenever I choose `date1`, I want to set `date1`'s value to `date2`'s value so that I use this code by using lambda expression

```
date1.setOnAction(event -> {
    date2.setValue(date1.getValue());
});
```

Everything works fine as butter but by using this code

```
Date2.setValue(Date1.getValue())
```

it automatically triggers the event of setOnAction of `Date2` and my other methods went nuts. Is there anyway to prevent this or another way to set `Date2`'s value without triggering the setOnAction event of `Date2`?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. From [`ComboBoxBase#onAction`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#onActionProperty):

> The ComboBox action, which is invoked whenever the ComboBox `value` property is changed. This may be due to the value property being programmatically changed, when the user selects an item in a popup list or dialog, or, in the case of `editable` ComboBoxes, it may be when the user provides their own input (be that via a `TextField` or some other input mechanism.

If you don't want the `onAction` handler of the second `DatePicker` to do anything when set programmatically by the `onAction` handler of the first then use a boolean flag:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  private boolean setting;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var date1 = new DatePicker();
    var date2 = new DatePicker();

    date1.setOnAction(
        event -> {
          setting = true;
          try {
            date2.setValue(date1.getValue());
          } finally {
            setting = false;
          }
        });

    date2.setOnAction(
        event -> {
          if (!setting) {
            System.out.println("Second DatePicker #onAction called!");
          }
        });

    var root = new HBox(15, date1, date2);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(30, 15, 30, 15));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```